# jquery on function and document ready

Tags: jquery, document-ready, jquery-on

I use the jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to attach an `onclick` function to a set of anchors in my website as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li>First <a href='#' title='delete' class="itemDelete">x</a></li>
  <li>Second <a href='http://www.repubblica.it' title='delete' class="itemDelete">x</a></li>
  <li>Third <a href='#' title='delete' class="itemDelete">x</a></li>
</ul>​

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '.itemDelete', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Should I insert the javascript code in the following block?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
});
```

If yes, why?

Comment: because then the javascript is executed when the library is loaded, otherwise you'll get errors that the jquery library is not existing..

A shorter way btw is: ``$(function() { ... });``

Comment: So, is it preferable to include all these kind of JS codes in a document ready block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That piece of code does not require document content to be fully parsed in any case because you are using `document` which always exists. The selector passed as second argument is not used in any way to retrieve elements, so the dom doesn't need to be ready for this.

You wouldn't be able to call `$(document).ready` in the first place if the above wasn't the case.

It's important to understand that behind the scenes you are attaching a direct, normal event listener to `document`. All the selector practically does is that your handler callback is not called if no elements matched your selector in the event propagation path. And obviously if propagation is stopped prematurely by lower level listeners, it wouldn't be fired in that case either.

Comment: Your answer seems to be different by that provided by Anthony Grist. He affirms that I mustn't use the `$(document).ready` block since the script is provided after that the related elements are loaded. You say something **stronger**, since you claim that, out of considering the script location inside the document, since I call the `on()` function on document, it is not necessary to use the `$(document).ready` since the document must be ready to call the `on()` function. Am I right?

Comment: @jonny_cage it has nothing to do with `on()` but what you pass to `$`. You pass `document` to `$` which is always available, thus methods called on it will work. If you pass a selector like `$("div")`, then it will only find the divs in the document that have been parsed at the time the call was made. Any method call on the resulting jQuery object will operate on just the divs that were found, which might be none, some of them or all of them depending on when and how you are calling it.

Comment: @jonny_cage His reasoning can be confusing because your code does not rely on the elements being there at all since you are doing `$(document)`. Were your code reliant on the elements being there, it would still work because the script element comes after them.

Comment: Ok! Now I understood (or rather I suppose that!!!). Hence, **if possible** it is preferable to use the `on()` function on the `document` element instead of using such a more specific selector.

Comment: @jonny_cage `document` is not an element :P But it's preferable from performance point of view to attach it to a normal element that is the closest common static parent. The propagation path to `document` is the longest one, thus having possible performance problems if abused. Another reason is that the `document` catches all events where as a common static parent catches only the events under it. You can use a normal element but in that case you must ensure you find it when it can be found. This means either doing it in domready or just in a script element that comes after the element.

Comment: Thanks! Very complete, precise and clear explanation! I'm going to accept your answer. PS: sorry for the inappropriate language, but I'm a Java developer... :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you don't need to. Since the `<script>` tag is after the HTML for the elements, your code will be executed **after** the elements have been loaded, removing the need to use a DOM ready event handler to ensure that they have been loaded.

That said, I usually prefer to include **all** my JavaScript code that works with elements on the page in a DOM ready event handler even when it's not strictly necessary; that way if I decide to move it elsewhere - such as the top of the page or to an external file - or change it in some other way it's not going to break.